# Fail to make mview using dblink(mysql)

Tags: mysql, oracle, text, dblink, materialized

In my project, I need to synchronize data from MySql to Oracle.

So, I tried to use Materialized View as below.

- step 1. make ODBC drive of MySql
- step 2. make DBlink to Mysql using ODBC
- step 3. make MView using DBlink

But in step3, I got a error message as below,

- ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

Data type of `APP_DESC` and `VERS_DESC` in Mysql table is "text",
and without that column, MView was made successfully.

Is it impossible to make and MView, about "text" column in dblink?

I need a help.

thanks in advance.

Mview Script is as follows:

```
create materialized view mv_meta_info 
build immediate 
refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (sysdate+1/1440) as 
SELECT APP_TYPE, APP_ID, VERS, APP_NM, CATE_ID, APP_URL, APP_DESC, 
       VERS_DESC, DOWN_CNT, HITS, PRICE, APP_SIZE, RATE, STATUS, 
       NEW_YN, RELEASE_DT, REG_ID, REG_DT, UDT_ID, UDT_DT, 
       SEED_APP_LIST, SEED_CATE_LIST 
FROM meta_info@DBLINK4MYSQL;
```

Comment: version is as below.
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: Posting `create materialized view...` script can help a lot to find out the problem.

Comment: create materialized view mv_meta_info
    build immediate
    refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (sysdate+1/1440) 
    as
    SELECT APP_TYPE
        ,APP_ID
        ,VERS
        ,APP_NM
        ,CATE_ID
        ,APP_URL
        ,APP_DESC /* text column*/
        ,VERS_DESC /* text column*/
        ,DOWN_CNT
        ,HITS
        ,PRICE
        ,APP_SIZE
        ,RATE
        ,STATUS
        ,NEW_YN
        ,RELEASE_DT
        ,REG_ID
        ,REG_DT
        ,UDT_ID
        ,UDT_DT
        ,SEED_APP_LIST
        ,SEED_CATE_LIST
    FROM meta_info@DBLINK4MYSQL;

Comment: Which columns is text?

Comment: And I've tried "TO_LOB" function on text column. Then, I got a message like this. "ORA-22992 : cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"

Comment: APP_DESC and VERS_DESC is the text in Mysql.

Comment: Did you tried casting datatypes? I mean `cast(APP_DESC as varchar2(4000))` in select statement.

Comment: I tried cast as you said. then, I got a messag like this. "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG"

Comment: I gave up about mview and decide to use [symmetricds](http://www.symmetricds.org/). Thanks @San.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try 
HS_NLS_NCHAR = UCS2 in gateway .ini file.